# How to access group matches in search macro that uses wildcards?

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a Word 2007 macro that finds text using wildcards, how do I access the group match values?

For example, if I script a macro that searches for `DATE:    (<*>)^13`, how would I find the value of the match group `(<*>)`?

Thank you,
Ben

---

```
Sub Search()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "DATE:    (<*>)^13"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like Word's find feature can do this. However, if I use VBScript Regular Expressions, my script should be able to get match results via the return value of the vbscript.regexp object's Execute method:
http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/excerpt/wdhks_1/index.html?page=4

Answer (score 0):

Good question, +1. Match groups aren't available in Word, but you can kind of hacky get around it. See the last entry on http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-128215.html for a solution.